# How to force Cleanup() for all my ViewModels

Tags: mvvm-light

My ViewModel instantiate resource that must be released when the program exits.

#### this in all my ViewModels:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    LocalServer Server { get; set; }
    Resource MyResorce { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel(LocalServer server)
    {
        this.Server = server;
        MyResource = new Resource();
    }

    public override void Cleanup()
    {
        if (MyResource != null)
            MyResource.Close();

        MyResource = null;
        base.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

#### this in ViewModelLocator

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel MainVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // Wrong!! The collection is empty!
        foreach (ViewModelBase vm in ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<ViewModelBase>() )
            vm.Cleanup();

        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<MainViewModel>();

        Messenger.Reset();
    }
}
```

But I noticed that `ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<MainViewModel>()`, returns all instances of a given ViewModel but if I ask `ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<ViewModelBase>()` like in this example it returns an empty collection!!

So, it's possible call CleanUp() for all my ViewModel using only one foreach?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You won't be able to do this in one go.  Here's why:

Internally, the SimpleIoc object contains a dictionary of instances:

```
Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>> _instancesReDictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>> _instancesRegistrygistry
```

When you call GetAllInstances what's actually happening under the hood is:

```
public IEnumerable<TService> GetAllInstances<TService>()
        {
            var serviceType = typeof(TService);
            return GetAllInstances(serviceType)
                .Select(instance => (TService)instance);
        }
```

Which in turn calls:

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
        {
            lock (_factories)
            {
                if (_factories.ContainsKey(serviceType))
                {
                    foreach (var factory in _factories[serviceType])
                    {
                        GetInstance(serviceType, factory.Key);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (_instancesRegistry.ContainsKey(serviceType))
            {
                return _instancesRegistry[serviceType].Values;
            }


            return new List<object>();
        }
```

Basically, all that it's doing is checking to see if your type exists in one or more dictionaries.  It's a straight comparison so whether an object A inherits from object B isn't taken into account.

What you could do, which requires more effort, but will do what you want, is use the Messenger to send a "Cleanup" message to all of your subscribing viewmodels:

ViewModelLocator:

```
 public static void Cleanup()
    {

        Messenger.Default.Send<CleanUp>(new CleanUp());
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel(LocalServer server)
    {
        this.Server = server;
        Messenger.Default.Register<CleanUp>(this,CallCleanUp);
    }
private void CallCleanUp()
{
    CleanUp();
}
```

This will work.  If you want to make it automatic then create a class that inherits from ViewModelBase that has this logic in it and have all you other viewmodels inherit from this class instead of ViewModelBase.