# How to reference a viewModel object in ViewModelLocator in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I'm trying to do some clean-up when my WPF app is closed. I know the ViewModelLocator.Cleanup() is getting called when the app shuts down, but I need to call the Cleanup method I have defined in my AvigilonViewModel class. The creation of an instance of AvigilonViewModel is not something I recognise, and I cant figure out how to use it.

ViewModelLocator.cs....

```
namespace Module.Config.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
            }
            else
            {
                //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            }

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AppState>();

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AvigilonViewModel>();
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public AvigilonViewModel Avigilon
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AvigilonViewModel>();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cleans up all the resources.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            Avigilon.Cleanup();
            /* I get error: An object reference is required for 
               the non-static field, method, or property
               'Module.Config.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator.Avigilon.get'  
            */
        }
    }
}
```

This similar question seems relevant but I get more erros when I try to implement it (I will post errors if required)...
[How to force Cleanup() for all my ViewModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578341/how-to-force-cleanup-for-all-my-viewmodels?rq=1)

**UPDATE - FOR ANSWER FROM har07**

ViewModelLocator.cs....

```
namespace Module.Config.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
            }
            else
            {
                //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            }

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AppState>();

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AvigilonViewModel>();
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public AvigilonViewModel Avigilon
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AvigilonViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<CleanUp>(new CleanUp());
        }
    }
}
```

AvigilonViewModel.cs....

```
namespace Module.Config.ViewModel.Modules
{
    public class AvigilonViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
    . . . 

        public AvigilonViewModel(AppState state)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<CleanUp>(this, CallCleanUp);
            . . . .
        }

        private void CallCleanUp
        {
           /* do actual cleanup */   
        }
    }
}
```

But what is `CleanUp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Aviglion.Cleanup()` in your code will call getter of `Aviglion` which is invalid call as the error message suggested, because the getter is not static and being called from a static method. More importantly, I believe that isn't what you meant to do.

Answer to the question you linked suggests that the way is by sending a clean up message to your `AvigilonViewModel` :

```
public static void Cleanup()
{
    Messenger.Default.Send<CleanUp>(new CleanUp());
}
```

..and make `AvigilonViewModel` listen to that particular message so it can responds the message by cleaning it self, for example :

```
public class AvigilonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public AvigilonViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<CleanUp>(this,CallCleanUp);
    }
    private void CallCleanUp()
    {
        //do the actual cleaning up here
        Cleanup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The error mesg I was getting when I try to implement this is: `The type or namespace name 'CleanUp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. I couldnt figure out if I was supposed to create CleanUp or I was missing something.
`

Comment: No what I meant was the CleanUp in `.Register<CleanUp>(` Do I have to create a type here on something. I have tried several things but cant figure out what to do her.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your comment. That supposed to be a user defined class... search about MVVMLight messenger if you're not familiar with that feature of MVVMLight and such coding style/pattern

Comment: I've updated my question to show all code for your answer. Cant figure out what I should put in for CleanUp. I jsut want to sent a command to cleanup - why do I need some type?

Comment: I'm not the right to person to explain this (that's why I commented as above)... But basically messages sent using `Messenger` are broadcasted, so you need to provide a type to differ which instance subscribe to which kind of message

Comment: You're welcome. Will be a lot better if you understand, but basically even an empty class (like `public class CleanUp {}`) will do...